# SSE in ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express, server-sent-events

I am trying to implement Server sent events in Expressjs project. Now, I created a socket connection using net api of NodeJs. I am getting streaming responses in socket. My doubt is when I try to send the streaming responses using res.send() , it says

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

My another doubt , what do I specify inside new EventSource(??) to successfully connect to that socket that is running in nodejs. Now I have written my server code in controllers folder !!

Any clarifications will be largely helpful !

Comment: Try to use `res.writeHead()` and `res.write()` instead. `res.send()` will help you send the headers also so it'll cause problems with streaming HTTP requests.

Comment: Any reason not to use [sse.js](https://github.com/einaros/sse.js)? And @Licson is correct, you can't use `res.send()` if you want the connection to remain open, since it will end the response once it has send the data to the client.

Comment: But,res.writeHead() and write() are not working too.I created sockets in the controllers(server-side) and trying to connect to it from file in public folder, whatever method I try, I am not able to connect my event source to it !! Thanks I will try the sse.js

Comment: have you solved this? I followed : http://www.smartjava.org/content/html5-server-sent-events-angularjs-nodejs-and-expressjs and it works great. however I am amazed I can't find a library to handle this for me.